# Python doesn't recognize class in the same directory

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I am relatively new to Python. I have cloned a class from a GitHub repository but it doesn't work for me. When I run main.py it doesn't recognize the class entity2rec which is in the same repository as main.py?

[image]

Comment: The directory is named `entity2rec`. What happens when you do `from entity2rec.entity2rec import Entity2Rec`?

Comment: Its not `entity2rec`. Thats fine. Its the file `config/properties.json`. The program is looking in the wrong folder for it.

Comment: Also don't post images. No one can search the image for the text it contains,

Comment: It absolutely *can* find it, it's even showing you an error message that is happening while executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your project path to the PYTHONPATH or if you are using pycharm you can directly set your project as source root. you can see the option with right click on your project folder.

Comment: Hi, I have set it as a source root but still the same!

Comment: have you tried setting pythonpath, refer https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/